# Sending binary data to HTTP server

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server

I am new to low level programming.I am trying to send binary data to the http server.At the moment i just fill up the byte array with numbers and send them to the server(eventually i want to send image file). I can see the request in the server log as 
`2016-05-18T23:30:26.688040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/users" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ed2b7852-7021-4642-a663-f9709e1aea70 fwd="99.89.114.63" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=221`

**Questions**

1.My question is as you can see in the log, what is `bytes=221` i thought if i sent byte array of length 32 i should see 32 bytes(or around 40s).And i made the buffer of length 1024 byte array, still in the server log is `bytes=221`.Are my bytes are even being sent?

2.How would i handle the bytes received on the server side just to be sure `client.write` actually succeeded?(Just in high level...doesn't matter you can guide me in any language,Java,ruby,C,NodeJS)

Here is my code.Thank you in advance.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define SSID "ssid"
#define PASS_SSID "password"
#define HOST "myapp.herokuapp.com"
WiFiClient client;


byte buffer[32];
int bufOffset = 0;
byte startByte = 0;
byte nextByte = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    checkConnection();
}

void loop() {

  if (client.connect(HOST,80)) {
           Serial.begin(115200);
           Serial.println("conected to the server");
           String start_request = "";
           String end_request = "";
           start_request = start_request  + "--AaB03x" + "\n"
                                   + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"cam.jpg\"" + "\n"
                                   + "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + "\n" + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
          end_request = end_request + "\n" + "--AaB03x--" + "\n";                       
          client.println("POST /api/users HTTP/1.1");
          client.println("Accept: */*");
          client.print("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x");
          client.println(start_request);

         //Fill the buffer with values
            nextByte = startByte++;
            for(int ii = 0; ii < sizeof(buffer); ii++) {
            buffer[ii] = nextByte++;
        }

          //write it to the server
        int count = client.write(&buffer[bufOffset], sizeof(buffer));

       //end the request
       client.println(end_request);   
        client.stop();
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should forget about MIME, that is only needed if you are sending *multiple* files to the server. Your best bet is to just send these headers, then a blank line, then your data:

```
POST /api/users HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 123
```

On the other end, you just look at "request.body" and it should have your binary data. (Replace 123 with `sizeof(buffer)`)

Comment: Thank you BraveNewCurrency. If i send a jpeg bytes though application/octet-stream, on the other hand how hard is it to handle those bytes back to the image(what do i need to do)?Thank you again.

Comment: Er, you don't need to "do" anything, bytes are bytes.  If you prefer, you can set Content-Type to be `image/jpg`. I suppose it could matter if your web server is checking content-types. (I assumed you were sending to a custom server, so you were not checking the content-type.)